# Transfer table to Memcache

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I have a large table and I'd like to store the results in Memcache.  I have Memcache set up on my server but there doesn't seem to be any useful documentation (that I can find) on how to efficiently transfer large amounts of data.  The only way that I currently can think of is to write a mysql query that grabs the key and value of the table and then saves that in Memcache. Its not a particularly scalable solution (especially when my query generates a few hundred thousand rows).  Any advice on how to do this?

EDIT:  there is some confusion about what I"m attempting to do. Lets say that I have a table with two fields (key and value).  I am pulling in information on the fly and have to match it to the key and return the value. I'd like to avoid having to execute ~1000 queries per page load. Memcache seems like a perfect alternative because its set up to use key value. Lets say this table has 100K rows. THe only way that I know to get that data from the db table to memcache is to run a query that loops through every row in the table and creates an individual memcache row.

Questions: Is this a good way to use memcache?  If yes, is there a better way to transfer my table?

Comment: memcache is key value storage. Please remember you can not query memcache, only pull existing data iff you know they key stored.

Comment: memcache is a *cache*, you should not import data to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Russ,

It sounds almost as if using a MySQL table with the storage engine set to **[MEMORY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html)** might be your way to go.

A RAM based table gives you the flexibility of using SQL, and also prevents disk thrashing due to a large amount of reads/writes (like memcached).

However, a RAM based table is very volatile. If anything is stored in the table and not flushed to a disk based table, and you lose power... well, you just lost your data. That being said, ensure you flush to a real disk-based table every once in a while.

Also, another plus from using memory tables is you can store all the typical MySQL data types, so there is no 1MB size limit.

Answer (score 1):

you can actually pull all the rows in an array and store the array in memcache

```
memcache_set($memcache_obj, 'var_key', $your_array);
```

but you have to remember few things

- PHP will serialize/unserialize the array from memcache so if you have many rows it might be slower then actually querying the DB
- you cannot do any filtering (**NO SQL**), if you want to filter some items you have to implement this filter yourself and it would probably perform worst then the DB engine.
- memcache won't store more then **1 megabyte** ...

I don't know what you try to achieve but the general use of memcache is:

- store the result of SQL/time consuming processing but the number of resulting row should be small
- store some pre created (X)HTML blobs to avoid DB access.
- user session storage

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the answer. I edited my question to give more clarity to what I"m trying to do. It seems like a perfect application for memcache but I could be totally wrong. 

Also, when you say Memcache won't store more than 1 MB, you mean I can't have a value > 1 MB.  I assume that I can have more than 1 MB stored in Memcache on my server....